# /etc/environment not working

Tags: ubuntu, path

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Recently, I accidentatlly removed `python`, causing a huge number of packages to be uninstalled. I reinstalled them, but now I am having problems.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/paul/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/paul/.rvm/bin
```

Note that there is no `/sbin` or `/usr/local/sbin`!

I have no idea how that happened!

Thus,

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y
...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
...
$ sudo shutdown now
sudo: shutdown: command not found.
```

I've gone looking. `/etc/environment` (which I have not touched) has

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

I've rebooted (a couple times). Why doesn't my path have `/sbin`?

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a new user

```
$ sudo adduser paul-test
$ su -- paul-test
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Also,

```
$ sudo su
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

So something is killing `/sbin` for me.

I've checked `.bashrc`.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And .profile

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

There is no `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`.

**FYI**

This the same problem described [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=69093) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1942520) and many other places.

They treat the symptom of `apt-get` not working, rather than correcting the real problem of no `/sbin`.

Comment: @Braiam, see updated question.

Comment: As your test account is not affected, the problem must be caused by something in your home directory. Search for other files that touch `$PATH`; I bet there's a line somewhere that sets `$PATH` to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games` before your `.bashrc` and `.profile` add the `$HOME/.rvm/bin` and `$HOME/bin` stuff.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich, what other files touch `$PATH` (for me only)? I realize I could included literally any file in `.bashrc` and `.profile`, but I've checked and I am not doing that.

Comment: what is the content of your `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: There is nothing that mentions my user. There is `root  ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

Answer (score 4):

The PATH can be set in any of

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Which ones are read depends on the kind of bash session you are running. What you want to do is grep for PATH in all these files.

```
$ grep PATH ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login \
            /etc/profile /etc/environment /etc/bash.bashrc
```

I have a nifty little bash function for just this sort of issue:

```
grep_bash(){
  for f in  ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login \
            /etc/profile /etc/environment /etc/bash.bashrc; 
  do 
    [ -e $f ] && grep -H "$@" $f; 
  done
}
```

I have that in my `.bashrc` so whenever something strange is going on, I use it to look for the relevant string in all possible config files. For example:

```
$ grep_bash PATH
```

As a side note, not having `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in a normal user's PATH is standard practice for most distributions. There is no reason for a normal user to have these directories in their path. I just checked on a Debian, and Ubuntu Server and a SuSe machine and only the Ubuntu seems to add `/sbin` to a normal user's path and it does so in `/etc/environment`. The other two only add it if the user is root.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP.  `~/.profile` is including the user's private `bin/`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` don't exist (I don't think they ever did), and `/etc/environment` is correct (and with the correct permissions according to another answer).  The PATH from /etc/environment still isn't being loaded, except it is being loaded for a newly-created user.  Ubuntu 12.04 - any further ideas?  (In the meantime, I'm just sourcing it in `~/.bashrc`, although I would like to know what broke)

Comment: @Izkata please post a new question. This all depends on exactly how you are logging in, `/etc/environment` should always be read, you are probably setting a path somewhere else so it is getting overwritten.

Comment: Do users on this site generally not VTC as Duplicate?  'Cause aside from python being removed, symptoms are identical.